# Simple past or present perfect with the word "always" and "never" for actions until now

Tags: present-perfect, past-simple

I would like to ask about the use of present perfect and simple past with the word " never" and "always" for actions until now.

As I know, for actions until now we should use present perfect.

But here is the note from my grammar book (Practical English Usage )

Quote from the book:

always, ever and never

In an informal style, a simple past tense is sometimes possible with always, ever and never when they refer to ‘time up to now’.
I always knew I could trust you. ( or I've always known . . .)

---

This means that in informal speaking, these pairs of sentences below have the same meaning. Is it right?

1.I **have never been** big on vegetables. I hate them.
= I **never was** big on vegetables.I hate them.

2.I **have never eaten** asparagus before. This is my first time.
=I **never ate** asparagus before.This is my first time.

3.**I've never thought** of blaming on you. I am just trying to help you understand the problem.
=**I never thought** of blaming on you. I am just trying to help you understand the problem.

Comment: [Please, please do not use all caps in your titles. Thank you. Please change your title and I will delete this comment.]

Comment: There are many questions along the lines of "What's the difference between present perfect and simple past?" And the important answer is: Any difference is a small difference, in what the sentence emphasizes or implies. *In general*, yes, those sentences are *close enough* to meaning the same thing. (The simple-past versions emphasize the past, the present-perfect emphasize the present. The "... of blaming you" example shows this difference best.)

Comment: *I have never eaten asparagus before* is the natural form where "before" means *before **now*** (I'm eating it as I speak, or just did, or am just about to). It's relatively dated / formal / literary to use Simple Past in a "current" context like that, but it's fine in, for example, *I never ate asparagus before I got married* (but there's absolutely nothing wrong with *I had never eaten asparagus before I got married* either).

Comment: @FumbleFingers,thanks so much.
 I understand your example (.... before I got married). But the thing I concern is the action until now. In your daily life, Do you often use simple past instead of present perfect in my examples in the original post?

Comment: @Andy Bonner, thanks so much for the answer.

You said "In general, yes, those sentences are close enough to meaning the same thing. ". This means using simple past in these situations instead of present perfect is not grammatically incorrect. This still happens in daily file.Right? Because some people, especially British told that only present perfect fits such situations on my first post.

Comment: 1. I would trust a book over anonymous people—including people like me here on Stack Exchange—as long as the book is written by a knowledgeable author, gone through an editing process, and been well received. A book by Michael Swan, published by Oxford, certainly meets these criteria.
 2. There's room for both to be right. Swan is advising you on what is "possible" "in an informal style." Much of what happens "in daily life" is not strictly correct. You have to decide whether you're asking about what is okay to use in casual conversation or what to use in formal academic writing.

Comment: @Andy Bonner,
Here is another situation, Could you please help me, I once heard on a movie:
A: Do you know Paris? B: oh, I went there 2 times.

I think it should be "I have been there 2 times".
Both are ok to say here and the listener still understand regardless of tense we chose. Right?

Comment: Yes, there is no *practical* difference in meaning especially in that example.

Comment: @Andy Bonner, thanks so much for your help.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that the ***reason*** I said *I have never eaten asparagus before* is the "natural" form where "before" means before ***now*** is because I'm assuming that context strongly implies *the only reason I'm saying this at all is specifically to point out that what I'm currently doing is "unusual" for me*. That's to say - it's an ***extreme*** example of something being said about the past that is ***very relevant*** to current time of speaking. In general, unless the "current relevance" is at least as "extreme" as that, you should probably just avoid the Perfect.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you.